# What is the crux of std::reference_wrapper implementation for the only purpose of makin std::ref work?

Tags: c++, c++11, ref, reference-wrapper

[The example on the page of `std::ref`/`std::cref`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/ref) shows the use of `std::ref`/`std::cref` to pass arguments to `std::bind` in a way that looks like `std::bind` is taking arguments by reference, when in reality it takes them all by value.

Looking at that example only, I could also be ignorant about the existence of `std::reference_wrapper`, and `std::ref` would just be a function that allows the behavior exhibited by the linked example.

That's what I mean by *`std::ref` works* in the title of the question and also in the following.

Mostly for fun I've tried implementing `std::ref` myself, and I came up with this:

```cpp
template<typename T>
struct ref_wrapper {
    ref_wrapper(T& t) : ref(t) {}
    T& ref;
    operator T&() const {
        return ref;
    }
};

template<typename T>
ref_wrapper<T> ref(T& t) {
    return ref_wrapper{t}; // Ooops
}

template<typename T>
ref_wrapper<const T> cref(const T& t) {
    return ref_wrapper{t}; // Ooops
}
```

where on the lines marked as `// Ooops` I have mistakely made use of [CTAD](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template_argument_deduction) because I was compiling with `-std=c++17`. By changing `ref_wrapper` to `ref_wrapper<T>` and `ref_wrapper<const T>` in the two cases corrects this.

Then I've had a peek into `/usr/include/c++/10.2.0/bits/refwrap.h`.

On the one hand, I see that my implementation of `ref`/`cref` closely resembles that of `std::ref`/`std::cref`.

On the other hand, I see that `std::reference_wrapper` is around 60 lines long! There's a lot of stuff in there, including `noexcept`, macros, copy ctor, copy `operator=`, `get`.

I think most of that is not relevant to the use of `std::reference_wrapper` ***only as a slave to `std::ref`***, but there's something which could be relevant, such as constructor taking a universal reference.

So my question is: what are the parts of `std::reference_wrapper` necessary and sufficients for `std::ref` to work, with respect to my skinny attempt?

I've just realized that there's a possible implementation of `std::reference_wrapper` [on cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/reference_wrapper) (which is less noisy than the one from GCC). Even here, however, there are things I don't undertand the reason of, such as `operator()`.

Comment: A lot of of how the functionality of reference wrapper should behave is in other parts of the C++ standard.  Things like `std::thread` and `std::bind` know about `std::referene_wrapper` and how it works so they can use that knowledge to work with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The logic that you're talking about is implemented entirely within `std::bind` itself. The main functionality it needs from `std::reference_wrapper` is the fact that it can be "unwrapped" (*i.e.*, you can call `.get()` on it in order to retrieve the underlying reference). When the call wrapper (*i.e.* object returned from `std::bind`) is called, it simply checks whether any of its bound arguments is a `std::reference_wrapper`. If so, it calls `.get()` to unwrap it, then passes the result to the bound callable.

`std::bind` is complicated because it is required to support various special cases, such as recursive `bind`ing (this feature is now considered a design mistake), so instead of trying to show how to implement the full `std::bind`, I'll show a custom `bind` template that's sufficient for the example on cppreference:

```
template <class Callable, class... Args>
auto bind(Callable&& callable, Args&&... args) {
    return [c=std::forward<Callable>(callable), ...a=std::forward<Args>(args)] () mutable {
        c(detail::unwrap_reference_wrapper(a)...);
    };
}
```

The idea is that `bind` saves its own *copy* of the callable and each of the args. If an argument is a `reference_wrapper`, the `reference_wrapper` itself will be copied, not the referent. But when the call wrapper is actually invoked, it unwraps any saved reference wrapper argument. The code to do this is simple:

```
namespace detail {
    template <class T>
    T& unwrap_reference_wrapper(T& r) { return r; }

    template <class T>
    T& unwrap_reference_wrapper(reference_wrapper<T>& r) { return r.get(); }
}
```

That is, arguments that are not `reference_wrapper`s are simply passed through, while `reference_wrapper`s go through the second, more specialized overload.

The `reference_wrapper` itself merely needs to have a relevant constructor and `get()` method:

```
template <class T>
class reference_wrapper {
  public:
    reference_wrapper(T& r) : p_(std::addressof(r)) {}
    T& get() const { return *p_; }

  private:
    T* p_;
};
```

The `ref` and `cref` functions are easy to implement. They just call the constructor, having deduced the type:

```
template <class T>
auto ref(T& r) { return reference_wrapper<T>(r); }

template <class T>
auto cref(T& r) { return reference_wrapper<const T>(r); }
```

You can see the full example [on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bf4d78782e05cc6a).

(The actual constructor of `std::reference_wrapper`, as shown on cppreference, is complicated because it needs to satisfy the requirement that the constructor will be SFINAE-disabled if the argument would match an rvalue reference better than an lvalue reference. For the purposes of your question, it doesn't seem necessary to elaborate on this detail further.)

Comment: If `reference_wrapper` offers a `operator T&() const` member, what is the point of having/using/needing also a `get` member? Wouldn't using the conversion operator instead of `get` avoid the need for a `unwrap_reference_wrapper`, thus having `c(a...);` in the first chunk of code? Doing so would cause the coversion from `reference_wrapper` to the type that the `callable`/`c` expects, am I wrong?

Comment: @Enlico Well, it's clear that you need one or the other. This toy example uses `.get()`, but it could just as well have been written to use `operator T&`. I'm not sure why the standard one has both - that's really a matter for a separate question.

Comment: Well, mine is actually a question to you, as I'm not sure that what I write in my previous comment is entirely correct. Furthermore, the simple fact that your solution using `get` is more verbose than the one I'm supposing, makes me think that I'm supposing something wrong, and so I'd like your opinion about it.

Comment: @Enlico I try to follow the spirit of `std::bind` - which requires the `reference_wrapper` to be explicitly unwrapped. This can matter in some cases, e.g., the callable is itself a template, or the callable expects some type that requires a user-defined conversion from `T&`. (continued ...)

Comment: Another thought is that my initial "perception" is that `std::ref` is a way to "trick" `std::bind`'s by value arugment policy, which clashes with your claim that it's `std::bind` to make that thing work.

Comment: @Enlico (... continued) if you want to rewrite this example using `operator T&`, I believe you can do so.

Comment: Oh, sure, if the callable is a template, it would instantiate on `reference_wrapper` without triggering the conversion _from_ `reference_wrapper`. Ok, I'm convinced!

Comment: @Enlico `bind` could have been specified to work in one of two ways: (1) store all arguments by value, then special-case on `reference_wrapper` when calling, or (2) unwrap the `reference_wrapper` upon initialization (storing a reference instead of a copy) so no special case is needed when calling. I am not sure why the standard one does (1) rather than (2); maybe it's just because reference members are annoying.